# Can we build an uncountable family of independent random variables with prescribed distributions?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, independence

Given a sequence of probability measures $(\mu_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$, I know how to build a probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$ and a sequence of $\mathbb{P}$-independent random variables $(X_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ such that, for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$, it holds that $\mathbb{P}_{X_n} = \mu_n$ (where $\mathbb{P}_{X_n}$ is the [pushforward measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushforward_measure) of $\mathbb{P}$ via $X_n$). This is just the classical construction of the product space.

I'm wondering if the same can be done for an uncountable family of probability measures. Precisely:

> Suppose that $I$ is an uncountable set and that $(\mu_i)_{i\in I}$ is a family of probability measures. Can we build a probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$ and a family of $\mathbb{P}$-independent random variables $(X_i)_{i \in I}$ such that, for each $i \in I$, it holds that $\mathbb{P}_{X_i} = \mu_i$?

As a reminder: the family $(X_i)_{i \in I}$ is said to be $\mathbb P$-independent if for any two *disjoint* subsets $J,K$ of $I$ we have that the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $(X_i)_{i \in J}$ and the one generated by $(X_i)_{i \in K}$ are $\mathbb{P}$-independent of each other.

Comment: Yes. A much more general result is Kolmogorov's Existence Theorem (aka Kolmogorov's Consitency Theorem)

Comment: Doesn't the "classical" construction of the product probability apply verbatim to any family of probabilities?